# New Wear UI Library breaking Android Studio Layout Editor

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, wear-os

I've imported the new [Wear UI Library](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/wear-ui-library.html) so that I can work with navigation drawers and such. However, upon importing it into my project, the Android Studio Layout Editor is no longer capable of previewing the design. I think it might have something to do with the [new](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html) `BoxInsetLayout`.

My Gradle dependencies look like this (`support_version` is `26.0.2`):

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "foo.bar.mayan"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "com.android.support:wear:$support_version" // the problem
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.4.2'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.5'
    ...
}
```

When I comment out the Wear lib (not the old *Wearable* lib), it runs fine:

[image: Functional layout editor preview]

However, when I include the Wear lib, and refactor the references to point to the new `BoxInsetLayout`, it breaks:

[image]

Note that *even if I continue to use the old `BoxInsetLayout`*, it has the same effect. As long as that library is depended on, the Layout Editor cannot preview the design.

Of course, I've tried cleaning Gradle, invalidating and restarting Studio, rebuilding, etc.

And yes, the problem also affects the Design tab of the Layout Editor.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible issue that I could see is that your library hasn't been downloaded properly. 
Remove the library from the cache and build project again. 
It should solve the issue.

Comment: For the record, this didn't solve the problem. There was no solution. I believe recent updates have fixed the bug.